# Form submit event not fired in Layout Page ?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having several views with `Begin Form` and `submit button` internally  but common thing is all referring to same layout .

I placed `$(form)` submit logic in layout (DRY) and i am expecting , when i click on submit button the logic in layout to fire but it isn't happening so .

**Layout :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $('form').submit(function () {
             if ($(this).valid()) {
                 $(':submit', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
             }
         });
</script>
```

**View:**

```
//layout refered
@using (Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
<button name="SUBMIT" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">SUBMIT</button>
}
```

if i have the same logic what i have in `layout` in my `every view` it's working great but when i have it in `layout` its seem to be having a issue .

Any workaround to make it work would be great .

Comment: wrap it with doc ready block.

Comment: yes that should work i tried it earlier but tried in different layout (messed up). thanks for bringing it up . please add as answer i'm glad to mark it . cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to wrap it within the document ready block because `form` submit event registration only be done if DOM is loaded.

```
$(function(){ // <-----this should be wrapped within this.
   $('form').submit(function () {
       if ($(this).valid()) {
          $(':submit', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: still i'm unable to believe what i have done , feeling stupid . eer ! . thanks jai .